# How to take input from multiple line or different line in c programming?

Tags: c, file

Here first number in the input means the number of lines that follow, and for each other line, we want to output how many numbers are in that line?

Input:

```
4
1   -2  10000   -50  20  7  445 
9
-98  876  65
223    9876452   212
```

Output:

```
7 
1
3
3
```

Comment: Show your best attempt.

Comment: `system("awk '{print NF}' input.txt")`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    char buff[32];
    fgets(buff, sizeof buff, stdin);//read first line. Is it necessary to check?
    int number_of_lines;
    sscanf(buff, "%d", &number_of_lines);

    while(number_of_lines--){
        int ch;
        int count_numbers = 0;
        while((ch = getchar())!=EOF && ch != '\n'){
            if(isspace(ch))
                continue;//Skip the preceding space
            int i = 0;
            buff[i++] = ch;
            while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && !isspace(ch) && i < sizeof(buff)-1)
                buff[i++] = ch;
            buff[i] = 0;
            ungetc(ch, stdin);//Return one over reading letter
            int num, len;
            if(sscanf(buff, "%d%n", &num, &len)==1 && !buff[len]){
                ++count_numbers;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", count_numbers);
        count_numbers = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work properly if it contains too long items.
To deal with such cases
Either skip input to the buffer early
It is necessary to change to a numeric validation automaton.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file line by line. Explicitly check for newline or EOF. I have not taken error handling into account, but it should not be ignored.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>



int main(){


    int n,i,j;
    char c;

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("example.txt","r");

    fscanf(fp,"%d",&i);

    j=i;

    int *count=(int)calloc(sizeof(int),i);//use calloc to initialize each index to 0;

    while(i){

        while(1){
            fscanf(fp,"%d",&n);


            count[j-i]++;

            c=fgetc(fp);

            if(c=='\n'||c==-1){//check for end of file or newline
                break;
            }


        }

    i--;

    }

    fclose(fp);
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
       printf("%d\n",count[i]);
    free(count);
    return 0;


}
```

Note: In the text file each line must be immediately ended by a newline after the last number and two numbers must be separated by exactly one space. The above program can be tweaked for general cases, this is just for demonstration!

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
        int t,count,i;
        char s[100];
        scanf("%d\n",&t);
        while(t--){
                gets(s);
                count=1;i=0;
                while(s[i]!='\0'){
                        if(s[i]==' ' && s[i+1]!=' ') count++;
                        i++;
                }
                printf("%d\n",count);
        }
        return 0;
}
```